# Weight averages to a scale

Tags: algorithm

I have a system that assigns users to experiments based on the experiment priority number. Each experiment has a weight that determines how often it will be chosen to be shown to the user. For example, a user can be assigned to experiment 1 with priority 100 over experiment 2 that has priority 80. Once we choose an experiment based on its weight, we check the experiment's traffic allocation number to assign the user to that experiment.

So even though experiment 1 has priority 100, if it's traffic allocation number is 80%, users who are set for that experiment will only be assigned to it 80% of the time. The other 20% will be assigned to a control group. However, the decision to allocate the user to the experiment or control of that experiment is based on the experiments priority. Other experiments with low priority are not as frequently shown to users.

How can I assign users to an experiment based on priority so that low priority experiments also get assigned frequently and are not starved.

What algorithm can I use to make sure that all experiments get assigned regardless of priority; though experiments with high priority will be assigned to users more often.

Comment: What you describe is a scheduling problem called "starvation". Google it and read about it and possible solutions.

Comment: The problem is pretty poorly defined; for example, there isn't a clear separation between choosing between experiments & being assigned to a control group.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me...  Do the weights correspond to some sort of probability? In other words: if experiment A has weight 100 and experiment B has weight 80, does this mean that on 180 overall users, 100 should be assigned (on average) to A and 80 to B?

Comment: No priority is arbitrary number from 1 to 100 where 100 is the highest ranking.

Comment: A priority of 100 means it has highest priority. Nothing to do with probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is poorly stated. Let's sort it out, and you say whether it's a useful sorting.

First, use the priority numbers to weight assignment to an experiment. Let `P_e` be the priority of experiment `e`.  Let `R_e` be the probability (0 to 1) that a user is assigned to experiment `e`.  Let's say the `n` experiments are arranged in some arbitrary sequence `e_0`, `e_1`... `e_(n-1)`. A reasonable formula for `R_e` is

```
R_e = P_e / sum(P_(e_i) for all i)
```

To decide which experiment a user is assigned to, generate a pseudorandom number `Z` in `[0..1)` and select `e_k` such that `k` is the smallest integer such that `Z < sum(R_j, j = 0..k)`. If the number of experiments is large, you'll want to do this by binary search.

Now that you know which experiment the user is part of, use a second pseudo-random number `Y`in `[0..1)` as a "coin toss" to decide if she's control or test. If `T_e` is the traffic allocation, then choose the test if `Y < T_e`, otherwise control.

This is a fair share scheme. No starvation.

**Example**

First, if you can't understand what's above, you'll need to study some math to be an effective programmer. This is pretty simple stuff.

Suppose experiments have weights

```
e_0 = 20, e_1 = 100, e_2 = 80
```

Their sum is 200, so the probabilities of selection should be:

```
R_0 = 20/200 = 0.1, R_1 = 0.5, R_2 = 0.4
```

The running sums of these probabilities look like this:

```
sum(0..0) = 0.1,   sum(0..1)= 0.6,   sum(0..2) = 1.0
```

These are the sums that must be searched (possibly by binary search) to determine `k`.

If the pseudo-random number Z is anything less than 0.1, select experiment e_k, where k=0; between 0.1 and less than 0.6, select k=1; 0.6 and above select k=2.

Now do the coin toss. If the traffic allocation is 0.75, then a toss less than 0.75 means test the user. Otherwise the user is control.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you

Comment: Mean by giving me actual numbers

Comment: @Jasmine added an example

Comment: What is this algorithm called?

Comment: @Jasmine It's just a commonsense fair share random assignment. It's too simple to have a formal name.